# Добавить рекурсивную проверку к SQL запросу на сущестование предков

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Надо посчитать общий размер всех актуальных версии документов.

В таблице **personal_document** хранятся версии документов, ***документ у которого самая свежая modification date и available = true считается последней актуальной версией.***

Надо добавить проверку, что у всех его предков-папок (лежат в таблице **personal_category**) available = true, если хоть у одной папке в цепочке предков available = false, значит эта папка была удалена и размер этого документа нам не нужен (даже если у него самого стоит available = true).

Запрос на подсчет размера всех актуальных версий документа без проверки предков.
Не могу сообразить как сюда вкорячить рекурсивную проверку предков-папок.

```
SELECT SUM(active_size) AS total_active_size FROM (
                SELECT SUM(pd.size) AS active_size FROM personal_document pd 
                JOIN (
                SELECT uid, MAX(modification_date) AS max_date FROM personal_document
                WHERE creator_uid = '0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6-a94d1f5d799a'
                AND available IS TRUE
                GROUP BY uid) max_dates ON (pd.uid = max_dates.uid AND pd.modification_date = max_date)
                GROUP BY pd.uid) as total
```

Запрос должен вернуть 0, но сейчас возвращает 24 (размер актуальной версии документа, без проверки что какой либо из его родителей удален).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE TABLE public.personal_document
(
    uid uuid NOT NULL,
    creation_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    modification_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT timezone('Asia/Yekaterinburg'::text, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    tenant_uid uuid NOT NULL,
    creator_uid uuid NOT NULL,
    description character varying(1024) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ext character varying(64) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(191) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    size bigint NOT NULL,
    storage_link character varying(2048) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    parent_uid uuid,
    tags uuid,
    available boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    CONSTRAINT personal_document_parent_uid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_uid)
        REFERENCES public.personal_category (uid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE public.personal_category
(
    uid uuid NOT NULL,
    creation_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT timezone('Asia/Yekaterinburg'::text, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    modification_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT timezone('Asia/Yekaterinburg'::text, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    tenant_uid uuid NOT NULL,
    creator_uid uuid NOT NULL,
    description character varying(1024) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    parent_uid uuid,
    available boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    CONSTRAINT personal_category_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid),
    CONSTRAINT personal_category_parent_uid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_uid)
        REFERENCES public.personal_category (uid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

INSERT INTO public.personal_category(
    uid, creation_date, modification_date, tenant_uid, creator_uid, description, name, parent_uid, available)
    VALUES ('fe818920-472d-409d-8b7d-74ae7c1082b5', '2020-02-19 12:00:23.629485', '2020-02-19 12:00:24.60576', 'a9c8662e-f4bc-4e8e-882d-310bf8e86198', '0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6-a94d1f5d799a', 'description 1', 'category name 1', null, true)
INSERT INTO public.personal_category(
    uid, creation_date, modification_date, tenant_uid, creator_uid, description, name, parent_uid, available)
    VALUES ('fe818920-472d-409d-8b7d-74ae7c1082b4', '2020-02-19 12:00:23.629485', '2020-02-19 12:00:24.60576', 'a9c8662e-f4bc-4e8e-882d-310bf8e86198', '0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6-a94d1f5d799a', 'description 1', 'category name 1', 'fe818920-472d-409d-8b7d-74ae7c1082b5', false);

INSERT INTO public.personal_document(
    uid, creation_date, modification_date, tenant_uid, creator_uid, description, ext, name, size, storage_link, parent_uid, tags, available)
    VALUES ('5f58fe01-1226-45ee-b2b7-b8ebd3eede0c', '2020-02-19 12:00:24.117', '2020-02-19 12:00:24.148247', 'a9c8662e-f4bc-4e8e-882d-310bf8e86198', '0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6-a94d1f5d799a', null, 'txt', 'name1', 24, 'hfhghg', 'fe818920-472d-409d-8b7d-74ae7c1082b4', null, true);

    INSERT INTO public.personal_document(
    uid, creation_date, modification_date, tenant_uid, creator_uid, description, ext, name, size, storage_link, parent_uid, tags, available)
    VALUES ('e6da3de1-b7f8-45c4-bd38-66015ec01e24', '2020-02-19 12:00:24.103', '2020-02-19 12:00:24.348853', 'a9c8662e-f4bc-4e8e-882d-310bf8e86198', '0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6-a94d1f5d799a', null, 'txt', 'name2', 14, 'jfjdsfb', 'fe818920-472d-409d-8b7d-74ae7c1082b4', null, false);

    INSERT INTO public.personal_document(
    uid, creation_date, modification_date, tenant_uid, creator_uid, description, ext, name, size, storage_link, parent_uid, tags, available)
    VALUES ('5f58fe01-1226-45ee-b2b7-b8ebd3eede0c', '2020-02-19 12:00:24.117', '2020-02-19 12:00:24.507633', 'a9c8662e-f4bc-4e8e-882d-310bf8e86198', '0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6-a94d1f5d799a', null, 'txt', 'name3', 24, 'fjghfj', 'fe818920-472d-409d-8b7d-74ae7c1082b4', null, true);
```

Comment: Приведите структуру таблиц, пример данных и требуемый результат на этом примере. Сейчас не ясно откуда берется рекурсия, если parent_uid ссылается на другую таблицу, а не на свою же, то откуда берется второй и далее уровни вложенности ?

Comment: @Mike Добавила, уровни вложенности есть у папок, в которых лежат документы и рекурсия по ним нужна.

Comment: Мы эта... не лечим по фотографиям. Вас просили привести *структуру таблиц, пример данных и требуемый результат на этом примере.* Структуру дайте в виде скриптов CREATE TABLE. Пример данных - в виде INSERT INTO. Результат должен быть именно для показанных данных.

Comment: В примере всего одна категория, как на ней то рекурсию отлаживать ? Слона надо есть по частям. Если я правильно понимаю что требуется,  надо сделать рекурсивный запрос только по таблице категорий, который получит для всех существующих категорий их итоговые статусы (если у родителя false, то все что в них вложено то же false). На выходе получаем выборку буквально uid категории, статус. После этого добавляем к нему текущий запрос, который собственно join'иним к той выборке

Comment: хотя нет, для нормальной производительности несколько сложнее, не заметил сразу что берется небольшая часть данных, по одному creater_uid. Но хотя бы подтвердите, что мои рассуждения про получение статуса категории верны

Comment: @Mike да, логика такая. С вложенностью вы правы, надо еще хотя бы категорию в категории, исправлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Recursive
DOC as(
    SELECT parent_uid, size
      FROM (
        SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by uid order by modification_date desc) rn
          FROM personal_document
         WHERE creator_uid = '0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6-a94d1f5d799a'
           AND available IS TRUE
     ) x 
    WHERE rn=1
),
REC as(
  select uid, available::int available, uid curr
    from personal_category
   where uid in(select uid from DOC)
 UNION ALL
  select REC.uid, C.available::int, C.parent_uid
    from personal_category C, REC where C.uid=REC.curr and REC.available=1
)
select sum(size)
  from DOC
  join (select uid
          from REC
         group by uid having min(available)=1
       ) x
    on DOC.parent_uid=x.uid
```

Подзапрос `DOC` получает то же, что ваш изначальный запрос, только немного другим способом (нумерует документы с одним uid в обратном порядке по дате и берет первые записи). Он дает нам uid требуемых категорий и размер самого документа.
`REC` собственно рекурсивный запрос по категориям, который начиная со всех категорий, которые встречались в DOC, собирает статусы их родителей.
Итоговый запрос берет минимальные статусы (приведенные к int) по результатам рекурсии. Таким образом он получает только те категории, где у всех родителей были только 1. Остается приклеить к нему изначальную выборку DOC и получить размеры

Comment: Спасибо, это офигенно круто. Немного не понимаю почему если убрать ORDER BY modification_date DESC в оконной функции, то у обоих версий документа в колонке rm будет 2. -->>                                       
         SELECT uid, count(uid) over(partition by uid) rn
          FROM personal_document
         WHERE creator_uid = '0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6-a94d1f5d799a'
           AND available IS TRUE         если этот запрос запустить как было, то они нумеруются, свежая версия получает 1, старая версия 2

Comment: @АлисаЛамехова Оконная функция с ORDER BY куммулятивная, т.е. накапливает свое значение от записи к записи. А без ORDER BY она дает у всех строк итоговое значение в окне, т.е. в данном случае количество записей всего с данным uid. (Хотя конкретно для row_number это несколько странно конечно, но думаю лучше чем давать ошибку неприменимости без order)

Comment: Да, все понятно, я пока разбиралась с этим запросом заменила row_number() на count() и он выдавал 2 для обоих версий, мне казалось, что результат не должен измениться, но теперь поняла, что это совсем разные вещи.

Comment: @АлисаЛамехова Вообще действительно не должен отличаться. я только что проверил даже, count(1) с order работает точно так же 1,2,...  правила поведения окна одинаковы для любых оконных функций

Comment: тогда все-таки непонятно, почему row_number()  с ордером или без возвращает 1 и 2, а count() с ордером - 1 и 2, без ордера - 2 и 2

Comment: @АлисаЛамехова Ой, действительно. я думал что row_number примерно как все остальное. Но тут уж ответ "потому что так сделали разработчики", это уже из разряда в Си "UB" (неопределенное поведение). Понятия "номер записи" без определения сортировки быть не может. Вот Oracle например дает ошибку 'missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification' при попытке использовать row_number без order by. А postgre решили не быть столь жесткими